# Issue with solving for $f(n-2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm taking precalculus this coming school year, and the review packet I'm working on asks me to find $f(n-2)$ for the function $$f(x)=x^2-6x+8.$$ I've got no idea how to find this, and a cursory internet search didn't return the results I've been looking for. An answer would be much appreciated, because I've never seen this before!

Thanks very much, 
Jack

Comment: Should the minus sign after $f(x)$ be an equal sign?

Comment: To clarify: you are given the function $f(x)=-x^2-6x+8$ or is your minus sign supposed to be an equal sign as in $f(x)=x^2-6x+8$?

Comment: I made the edit assuming your $-$ meant $=$. Please comment on whether this was your intent or not

Comment: Put brackets around all the $x$'s ... $f(\color{red}{x})=(\color{red}{x})^2-6(\color{red}{x})+8$. Now everywhere that you see $\color{red}{x}$ replace it with $\color{blue}{n-2}$ ... $f(\color{blue}{n-2})=(\color{blue}{n-2})^2-6(\color{blue}{n-2})+8$ & now do the algebra.

Comment: gt6989b, Yes, that was my intent. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $f(n)$ then to find $f(5)$ you plug in $5$ instead of $n$ on the right-hand side. So too here,
$$
f(x) = x^2-6x+8
$$
and so
$$
f(n-2) = (n-2)^2 - 6(n-2) + 8.
$$
Can you simplify?

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify before to calculate the value of the function at (n-2)

$$f(x)=x^2-6x+8= (x-2)(x-4)$$
$$f(n-2)=(n-2-2)(n-2-4)$$
$$f(n-2)=.......$$